# WCF, executing Events?

Tags: c#, wcf

While continuing to learn WCF, I'm trying to make it work with events.

In this example, upon a button click in a form, I want my wcf service to execute and event that would be trigger something in other form that are connected to this service.

That's the code for the Form1.

```
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   client.TimeShowEvent += new EventHandler(TimeShowEvent);
   ///// SAYS THAT IT DOES NOT CONTAIN A DEFINITION FOR TimeShowEvent
}

MyWcfService1.IfaceServiceClient client = new MyWcfService1.IfaceServiceClient();

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      MyWcfService1.IfaceServiceClient client = new MyWcfService1.IfaceServiceClient();
      client.passTime();
   }
   catch
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Service not availabe!");
   }
}

void TimeShowEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox2.Text = client.timestring;
   //// SAYS THAT IT DOES NOT CONTAIN A DEFINITION FOR timestring
}
```

and for the service:

```
namespace wcfLib
{
   [ServiceContract]
   public interface IfaceService
   {
       [OperationContract]
       int wordLen(string word);

       [OperationContract]
       string passTime();

        ///// DO I NEED TO SOMEHOW DECLARE THE VARIABLES ( timestring ) AND EVENTS ( TimeShowEvent ) HERE?
   }
}
```

Service implementation:

```
public class StockService : IfaceService
{
    public event EventHandler TimeShowEvent;

    public string timestring = "none";

    public string passTime()
    {
        TimeShowEvent(this, new EventArgs());
        timestring = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        return "";
    }

    public int wordLen(string word)
    {
        return word.Length;
    }
}
```

Service host app:

```
public class Service
{
    static void Main()
    {
        ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(StockService), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/wcfLib"));
        serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IfaceService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");
        serviceHost.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Press return to terminate the service");
        Console.ReadLine();
        serviceHost.Close();
    }
}
```

Do I need to somehow declare events and variables in [ServiceContract]? Is so, how?...

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a service reference to your service, your client gets access to the service methods - and **only** to the service methods.

The event handler `TimeShowEvent` in your service implementation class will be present and usable **on the server-side only** - it will **not** be available on the client side.

If you want to have something to call, you need to define another service method - those are "mirrored" in the client-side proxy class - and only those.

The only connection your client-side proxy and your server share are the service methods defined in your service contract, and the data that gets passed for those methods - as serialized (XML) messages. There's no "magic link" between client and server - the client can't "reach into" the server class and read stuff from there or call events on that class. There is no "remote object" connection between the two.

Comment: oh, I see. thanks. :) yet is there a way for the service to talk back to the client? For example a chat application, one client passing a string to the service and the service passes it to the other client.

Comment: @Rob: there are some "duplex" bindings (e.g. `wsDualHttpBinding`) - but I don't really know how well and reliable they work (I never use them myself)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
string timeString;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //You already declared client, so you don't need to do it again.

            //Assign the value from your wcf call to a local variable
            timeString = client.passTime();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Service not availabe!");
        }
    }
```

and modify the service to return a string:

```
public string passTime()
    {
        TimeShowEvent(this, new EventArgs());
        return DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    }
```

and your event:

```
void TimeShowEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = timeString;  //this is your local variable
    }
```

And your event handler needs to be in the client.  The wcf service will not know anything about the event that called it or used its result.